# How to get a randomly shuffled sequence based on shuffle intensity indicator?

Tags: shell-script

I need to get a sequence of shuffled elements in a range, but **I want to determine *how much* this sequence should be shuffled**. For example, suppose our range is `1-100` and I want a sequence of 10 numbers. All of these sequences are valid:

```
{1,5,17,43,44,67,77,77,83,90}

{1,90,17,43,44,77,77,67,83,5}

{67,5,90,77,43,77,17,1,83,44}
```

As you can see, all of elements of the three sequences are the same, but they are shuffled with different intensity. The first sequence is sorted, (that is, is not shuffled), the second one is shuffled a little, and the last one is shuffled much more ( and perhaps only this one is really shuffled :) ).
Now I want a method so that I can get such sequences based on an indicator called shuffle intensity indicator, or `si2`.

### My Approach

*I hope this section doesn't make my question a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I only want to share my approach and it is not point of the question. **However, I will be happy if my questions in this section are answered.***

I used the following series of commands in order to get a sequence of 2,000,000 numbers in the range `1-2000000`:

```
for i in `seq 10000`; do 
    shuf -i 1-2000000 -r -n 100 | sort ; shuf -i 1-2000000 -r -n 100; 
    done > input
```

As you can see, the sequence has 10,000 chunks of 100 numbers that are decussate  sorted and shuffled sequences. I can, for instance, use `150` instead of first `100` and `50` instead of second, so the *shuffle intensity* gets quadruple. But this approach has some problems (at least for me).

- This approach is **too slow** ( and **I want to know why.** I found that the bigger the chunks are, the faster the operation will be.).
- It also requires **manual determination** of the two numbers that
  indicate shuffle intensity.
- And, perhaps most importantly, it is **not really shuffled randomly**. As
  you can see, the chunk sizes are the same.

### Ideal solution

Ideally, I want a script with options like this:

```
myshuf SI2 MIN MAX NUM [OUTPUT]
```

while `MIN` and `MAX` determine the range, `NUM` determines the size of sequence and `SI2` is shuffle intensity indicator. The higher the `SI2` is, the more intense shuffle will be. `SI2` will be between 0 and 10.

So

```
myshuf 0 0 2000000 2000000
```

gives a sorted sequence of 2,000,000 numbers between 0 and 2,000,000 and

```
myshuf 10 0 2000000 2000000
```

gives a very-good-shuffled sequence.

If you are curios to know why I need such sequences, I should say I have some sorting algorithms and I want to try each one and see their time complexity on different kinds of inputs.

Answer (score 1):

One way to shuffle with varying intensity could be to take a sorted list and make a varying number of random permutations (making sure elements are not moved more than once).

```
shuffle() {
  awk -v n="$1" '
    {line[NR]=$0; i[NR] = NR}
    END{
      if (n > NR/2) {
        print "two many permutations"
        exit(1)
      }
      srand()
      for (x = 1; x <= NR; x++) {
        # shuffle the list of indicies
        y = int(rand() * NR) + 1
        tmp = i[x]; i[x] = i[y]; i[y] = tmp
      }
      for (x = 1; x <= n; x++) {
        # get the lines to permute from the head of the shuffled
        # list of indices
        y = i[x*2-1]; z = i[x*2]
        tmp = line[y]; line[y] = line[z]; line[z] = tmp
      }
      for (x = 1; x <= NR; x++) print line[x]
    }'
}

$ seq 10 | shuffle 0 | paste -sd , -
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
$ seq 10 | shuffle 1 | paste -sd , -
1,2,6,4,5,3,7,8,9,10
$ seq 10 | shuffle 5 | paste -sd , -
9,6,5,10,3,2,8,7,1,4
```

`shuffle 5` will guarantee that none of the elements will have retained their original position (shuffle `n` guarantees 2*n elements get a different position). There are some shufflings it will never achieve. For a 1,2,3 list for instance, the only possible outcomes are `2,1,3`, `3,2,1` and `1,3,2`. Not `3,1,2`

With a `shuffle 5`, you could also end up with `6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5` which you might is not very shuffled.